# Add XML prefix for the root element with Symfony XML serializer

Tags: php, xml, symfony, root, prefix

I'm using symfony serializer in order to encode a class in XML:

```
        $serialized = $this->serializer->serialize(
        $content,
        'xml',
        [
            XmlEncoder::ROOT_NODE_NAME => 'dummy',
            XmlEncoder::REMOVE_EMPTY_TAGS => true,
            XmlEncoder::FORMAT_OUTPUT => true,
        ],
    );
```

This code generates a normal XML, but I want to add a prefix to the root element only. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I modified this line:

```
XmlEncoder::ROOT_NODE_NAME => 'p:dummy',
```